# Finding all lattice point in bounded region

Tags: linear-algebra, algorithms, linear-programming

I have a closed region in n-dimensional space bounded by two inclined hyperplane and plane along the axes. What algorithm can I use to locate all the lattice points in the region?

$$ \sum_{i=0}^n a_ix_i \le N; \ \sum_{i=1}^n b_i x_i \ge M;\ x_i \ge 0;\ a_i, b_i, N, M \in \Bbb Z_+
$$

This is related to this question on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36321558/find-the-set-of-integers-for-which-two-linear-equalities-holds-true).

**UPDATE::**

The question comes from finding all solutions of linear equation for 
$$ AY = B$$
where $Y = (y_1, \dots, y_{n+2})^T$ and $y_i \ge 0$ is an integer assuming that particular solution also consists of integer. Here $A$ is of the form

$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & \dots & 1 \\ 
p_1 & \dots & p_{n+2}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Here $p_i \ge 0$ is strictly increasing sequence of positive integers. How do I find the upper bound and lower bound for the value of $x_i$?

Mathematica solves quickly under a minute.

```
Solve[{97 n1 + 89 n2 + 42 n3 + 20 n4 + 16 n5 + 11 n6 + 6 n7 + 2 n8 - 
    185 > 0, 
  -98 n1 - 90 n2 - 43 n3 - 21 n4 - 17 n5 - 12 n6 - 7 n7 - 3 n8 + 205 >
    0,
  n1 >= 0, n2 >= 0, n3 >= 0, n4 >= 0, n5 >= 0, n6 >= 0, n7 >= 0, 
  n8 >= 0}, {n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, n6, n7, n8}, Integers]
```

Comment: IDK if it's correct place for asking. I couldn't think anywhere else other than SO and M.SE. Please forgive me if it was inappropriate.

Comment: @hardmath edited the question. I think this is related to the Mixed Integer Linear programming. I don't have any function to minimize or maximize. Just need the lattice points. :(

Comment: @hardmath I need the list of points :S Is there any other way where I can avoid looking all points in hypercuboid made by the intercepts of first inequality?

Comment: The SO post you link to suggests the size of $n$ is rather modest.  How big should it be in your practical application?

Comment: @hardmath I don't know. I was given $n=8$. I am assuming $n\le10^3$. Anyway this came from [coin change problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change-making_problem) constrained to exact number of steps (coins). I modelled into $AX = B$ and trying to find all possible particular solutions for which $x_i \ge 0$ where $(x_i)^T = X$.

Comment: I had your Question in mind when I made my way through clarifying and writing something up for [this recent one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1724708/efficient-time-complexity-algorithm-for-linear-programming-problems).  In your recent Update I was not clear how the $x_i$ related to $y_i$, although it seems you may have introduced a couple of extra variables to make the original linear inequalities into equalities??

Comment: @hardmath I found the inequality by adding all null spaces of the equality relation. Adding particular solution to null spaces such that all elements of solutions are greater than zero.

Comment: I'm not sure I get that approach.  The null spaces of your equality relation $AY=B$ will not have vectors that are all positive components, but somehow you wind up in the inequalities with all positive coefficients.  Would you be interested in algorithms that directly solved the equality relations?

Comment: @hardmath It's part of my work :( The original question was like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36409707/c-sharp-writing-a-recursive-function-which-returns-list-of-list-of-integers) I thought I would reduce it into [linear system and solve it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36321558/find-the-set-of-integers-for-which-two-linear-equalities-holds-true).