# Efficient (time complexity) algorithm for Linear Programming problems

Tags: linear-programming, integer-programming

I have an inequality of the form:

$$\sum_{i=1}^n a_i\cdot x_i \ge a_0$$

where $a_i\gt 0$ for all $i$. Subject to this and $x_i\ge 0$ for all $i$, I have to minimize the expression:

$$\sum_{i=1}^n b_i\cdot x_i \;\;\text{ where } b_i\ge 0$$

What would be the most efficient way in terms of time complexity to solve this problem computationally? Please point towards relevant algorithms. Also I am open to Monte Carlo algorithms for the same if the deterministic version is hard.

EDIT: There has been a modification is my application design which calls for all involved quantities to be integers(non-negative). Now since this problem falls under the category of NP-Hard problems I am looking for good local search based approaches to the problem.

Comment: I dont know anything yet

Comment: You should perhaps learn about the simplex algorithm before asking what "the most efficient" algorithm is.  Some familiarity with time complexity is needed to appreciate any Answer that your Readers might share with you.

Comment: Is there anything else i might need to know? Thanks for the input!

Comment: Are you familiar with matrix algorithms to solve systems of linear equations?  As Linear Programming problems are systems of linear *inequalities*, knowing the use of elementary row operations to solve linear systems would give you some helpful background.

Comment: Yes I know how to solve systems of linear equations using matrix operations. I will look into Dantzig's method for LP.

Comment: You know the existance of the domain called "Linear programming". You could play with very efficient black boxes like "linprog" or "sedumi" in Matlab and solve your own problems. I say black boxe because it is the algorithm inside are very optimized ans switch between the simplex algorithm (@hardmath has used this term) and another method called interior point method. In my opinion, it is time consuming to learn to do simplex algorithm "by hand", without much profit. It is better to concentrate on duality and different (often witty) methods to convert problems into linear programming issues.

Comment: I tweaked your math formatting a bit.  As it reads, you have only a single "problem" constraint (inequality) plus some standard non-negativity constraints on the variables.  Since the coefficients of the objective function are nonnegative and those of the problem constraint are all positive, the objective function can be minimized essentially "by inspection".  Is this really the Linear Program you want to solve, or has it gotten over-simplified in the "retelling"?

Answer (score 1):

As stated the problem is solved by picking the index $i$ for which $b_i/a_i$ is smallest.  Then setting $x_i = a_0/a_i$ and all other variables to zero, we get the objective function summing to:

$$ a_0 \cdot \frac{b_i}{a_i} $$

Time complexity is thus $O(n)$.  Let me give an example to illustrate that restricting the variables (and perhaps coefficients) to integers makes the problem more difficult but still tractable.

---

The following "coin change" example is taken from the Wikipedia [dynamic programming article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming), where it is used to motivate an alternative to the greedy algorithm.

Suppose coins are available in denominations $1,4,5,15,20$.  We are asked how best to make up $23$ in change, where "best" means the fewest number of coins.

> Minimize $g(x) = x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5$ such that $x_i \ge 0$ are integers and $$ 1x_1 + 4x_2 + 5x_3 + 15x_4 + 20x_5 = 23 $$

If we treat this as a linear programming problem, relaxing the integer constraint to allow real (rational) values of the $x_i$, then as outlined in the answer above a minimum value of $g(x)$ is achieved by taking $x_5 = 23/20 = 1.15$ (with other variables set to zero).  Note that the "problem" constraint is satisfied as equality (a tight constraint) because the solution is a vertex of the polytope formed by the intersection of half-spaces defined by all constraints (the problem constraint as well as the non-negativity constraints).

One way to satisfy the integer constraint is by a *greedy algorithm* that selects the largest denomination coin as many times as possible without exceeding the amount of change to be made.  Following this procedure we would choose $x_5=1$ to select a denomination $20$ coin, after which change still needs to be made for $23-20 = 3$ left over.  Since only the denomination $1$ coin can be used without exceeding that remainder, this greedy algorithm uses four coins in all to give *exact change* (equality):

$$ 23 = 20 + 1 + 1 + 1 $$

But this doesn't actually minimize $g(x)$ since a solution with three coins is possible:

$$ 23 = 15 + 4 + 4 $$

Finding that solution, with the equality constraint, can be done using the dynamic programming approach outlined in the article.  It essentially involves a search in order to overcome the limitations of the "follow your nose" greedy algorithm.

We want to use the example to illustrate that relaxing the *equality* constraint to an inequality allows integer solutions with even fewer coins!  That is:

$$ 1x_1 + 4x_2 + 5x_3 + 15x_4 + 20x_5 \ge 23 $$

has non-negative integer solutions with as few as two coins.

The attentive Reader will notice that with this "relaxed" inequality (problem constraint) the earlier algorithm comes back into consideration.  That is, by checking which index has the smallest $b_i/a_i$ (where in this coin change case all the $b_i=1$), we find the noninteger solution $g(x) = 1.15$ (i.e. $x_5 = 1.15$ and other $x_i$ zero).

Thus to obtain an integer solution we can "round-up" $x_5$ to two coins, and this is indeed an optimal solution since any integer-valued solutions must give us $g(x) \ge \lceil 1.15 \rceil = 2$.

However we cannot always achieve such a simple solution for the kinds of problems described here.  Our easy success with the coin changing problem depended on the fact all $b_i = 1$ here, which meant:

$$ \left\lceil a_0 \cdot \frac{b_i}{a_i} \right\rceil = b_i \cdot \lceil a_0/a_i \rceil $$

whichever index $i$ gives the least $b_i/a_i$.

The general case of your problems will call for a search structured by dynamic programming, or one of the other approaches mentioned in the [integer programming article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming).

Comment: im srry but this is not obvious to me as it stands , could you possibly make it a bit clearer why this might work?

Comment: Ok I see what you mean... could you suggest what can be done if all quantities are assumed to be integers i.e $a_i$, $b_i$ , $x_i$ are all integers??

Comment: Generally restricting a linear prorgramming problem to make the variables integers instead of real numbers results in a different kind of problem (see [Integer programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming))..  Still, if you have only one "problem" inequality to satisfy, the solution can be found quickly by doing a carefully structured search.

Comment: I've added further material to the answer, explaining how restricting to integer variables can change the difficulty of solving these problems.